# Communicate Arduino and Intel Edison using XBee

Tags: xbee, intel-edison

I am learning how to use XBee S2 to communicate with two Arduinos in API mode. Communication is successful. The problem is when I use XBee S2 with Intel Edison. I am not able to receive the data on the Intel Edison.

I would like to know if the Arduino receiver code can be used in the Intel Edison or do I have to use Python to receive the data by XBee.

Comment: Can you elaborate more? For example, are you using stock image or latest from the community (https://github.com/edison-fw/)? Any links to what xbee S2 is?

Comment: Hi. I have installed the latest version of the XCTU tool, and updated the XBEE firmware.  I have also seen that I needed to activate JV = 1 and finally I have managed to communicate the coordinator, router and end devices.
 
Hope this information helps. Thanks